# PageMenu title Background Image

Tags: ios, swift

everyone, I'm Using PageMenu in swift3 app. I want to add menu title background image. Is it possible? Let me explain I have implement page menu it gives me output like in image [image: PageMenu Image]

But I need rectangle shape menus so the solution was in my mind add background Image. Attached Required menu. I have background rectangle Image but how can I implement in PageMenu. or any other solution for this? Thanks

[image: Required Menu]

Comment: Sorry, do you mean adding the white parallelogram to the background of the highlighted menu item?

Comment: Yes I mean adding the white parallelogram to the background of the highlighted menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the GitHub documentation for PageMenu, it seems that MenuViewItem straightforwardly subclasses UIView. In which case you can do what you want by adding a sublayer to the view's layer. So if you had a MenuItemView called myMenuItemView:

```
let parallelogramLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
parallelogramLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
parallelogramLayer.frame = bounds

let parallelogramPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
parallelogramPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0))
parallelogramPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0))
parallelogramPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - 10, y: bounds.height))
parallelogramPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height))
parallelogramPath.close()

paralellogramLayer.path = parallelogramPath.cgPath

myMenuViewItem.layer.addSublayer(parallelogramLayer)
```

Obviously you'd need to add/remove the layer depending as to whether the menu item is active, but hopefully this gives you the idea. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for answer. CAShapeLayer giving me error "use of undeclayer type CAshapelayer"
and What is bound in this line of code "parallelogramLayer.frame = bounds"

Comment: Apologies- I think you need to import QuartzCore at the top of the file for CAShapeLayer. A view's bounds property is just a rectangle the same size as the view but with origin 0, 0. It cones in very handy when sizing subviews for obvious reasons.

Comment: import QuartzCore is not working i have also added QuartzCore framework in xcode but still facing same error

Comment: See the edit: the class is CAShapeLayer, capital S, capital L. (The answer above was typed on my 'phone.)